# How to best sort xml records with xslt?

Tags: xslt

Here's my source xml file, it has records like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<A msgVersion="revision2.0" xmlns="abc:def.ghi" >
    <B>
        <ID>12345</ID>
    </B>
    <record>
        <name>Foo</name>
        <recTime>2020-03-30T23:59:36.62Z</recTime>
    </record>
    <record>
        <name>Bar</name>
        <recTime>2020-03-31T23:59:36.62Z</recTime>
    </record>
    <record>
        <name>Car</name>
        <recTime>2020-03-29T23:59:36.62Z</recTime>
    </record>
</A>
```

I want to transform it so that all the records are sorted by "recTime", like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A msgVersion="revision2.0" xmlns="abc:def.ghi">
  <B>
    <ID>12345</ID>
  </B>
  <record>
    <name>Car</name>
    <recTime>2020-03-29T23:59:36.62Z</recTime>
  </record>
  <record>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <recTime>2020-03-30T23:59:36.62Z</recTime>
  </record>
  <record>
    <name>Bar</name>
    <recTime>2020-03-31T23:59:36.62Z</recTime>
  </record>
</A>
```

I'm playing with xslt, but I'm not familiar with it.  Here's what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ss="abc:def.ghi">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:variable name="newline">
  <xsl:text>
  </xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <A>
      <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="/ss:*/ss:B" />
      <xsl:for-each select="/ss:*/ss:record">
        <xsl:sort select="ss:recTime"/>
        <record>
          <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
          <name><xsl:value-of select="ss:name"/></name>
          <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
          <recTime><xsl:value-of select="ss:recTime"/></recTime>
          <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
        </record>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </A>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's what it outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A xmlns:ss="abc:def.ghi">
  <B xmlns="abc:def.ghi"><ID>12345</ID></B><record>
  <name>Car</name>
  <recTime>2020-03-29T23:59:36.62Z</recTime>
  </record><record>
  <name>Foo</name>
  <recTime>2020-03-30T23:59:36.62Z</recTime>
  </record><record>
  <name>Bar</name>
  <recTime>2020-03-31T23:59:36.62Z</recTime>
  </record></A>
```

It has a few problems:

1. The root element 'A' is missing the attribute msgVersion="revision2.0"
2. Element 'B' should not have a namespace, since it did not in the source xml
3. The xml formatting (spacing and new lines) isn't pretty, but that's not high priority

I also have a gut feeling I'm going things the hard way.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"Element 'B' should not have a namespace, since it did not in the source xml"* You are mistaken about that. Default namespaces are inherited. **All** the elements in the source XML are in the `"abc:def.ghi"` namespace.

Comment: Rather confusing that your headline asks about sorting, but the sorting part of this stylesheet seems to be working perfectly well, and the detailed questions are unrelated to sorting.

Comment: Sorry if that was confusing.  I realize I had the sort part working, but I wasn't sure if it was the best way.  That's why I asked "How to best sort" in the headline.  And sure enough, my attempt was not the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ss="abc:def.ghi">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/ss:A">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | ss:B"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ss:record">
            <xsl:sort select="ss:recTime"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```